# How to create n-collection deep url in Django Rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

We are creating a service where the user can push data through API to create resources and collections. Basically we want to offer the user one collection where they can add single data resources, or collections with subcollections and resources. Quite close analogy is a file-system with its files and folders.

This kind of system would create urls like:

```
www.example.com/api/mycollection/books/TheBook
www.example.com/api/mycollection/thing
www.example.com/api/mycollection/something/theimportant/myvisa
```

As you can see, between the final data resource and "mycollection" there can be any amount of collections depending on how the collection owner has pushed data to the API earlier. Each collection should also be callable by GET to find out its content.

With Django Rest Framework I know that I can define urls like this:

```
(r'^api/(?P<rootcollection>\w+)/(?P<subcollection>\w+)/$', views.ListEntries.as_view()),
```

and I can take the parameters into API-view to be used in database queries or whatever. My question is how I can generalize this pattern so that there can be any amount of these parameters?

My friend suggested to make an APIView which responds to urls which begin by "^api/" and then handle the rest of the url in APIView by extracting rest of the url parts to a list of words. Based on these words I can make a query to the db and finally construct a JSON-response based on the request. Does this idea make any sense or is there better solutions in DRFW?

Comment: Essentially you want to override "RelatedField" and provide a way for the resolution to occur. You could start off https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers